# Is there a gender field in LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin-api

My application gets users' information from LinkedIn and I could not find a way to get someone's gender from LinkedIn.

Is it possible?

Does LinkedIn even have a gender field?

Comment: you can use this api http://api.namsor.com/onomastics/api/json/gendre/John/Smith

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope. Check this; https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/javascript-api-gender-information-authenticated-user

Answer (score 2):

You can add your own gender by clicking Me > Settings & Privacy > Personal demographic information.

Linkedin calls this [Self-ID Information](http://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/102697).